# Use of basic and digest authentication with TSAClientBouncyCastle in iText7

Tags: c#, .net, itext7

I have a scenario to use Basic and Digest authentication while communication with TSA in case of document timestamping using iText7.
I am providing the credentials of proxy server but getting error "405-Method not allowed".
My code snippet is following:

ITSAClient tSAClient = new TSAClientBouncyCastle(tsaUrl, userName, password, estimatedSize, hashAlgo);

Could someone guide me in this scenario
Regards

Comment: You can simply take the `TSAClientBouncyCastle` code (iText Core is open source after all) and change it to meet your requirements. Currently in its `GetTSAResponse` it uses `SignUtils.GetTsaResponseForUserRequest` in which Basic Authorization is hard-coded. Replace this call by some similar helper method which is more flexible in respect to authorization.

Comment: @mkl
Thank you for the provided solution. It works like a charm. Thumbs up.

Comment: Do you want to create an actual answer (instead of the mere comments here) to your question? Or shall I?